# Why in Vue 3, when using a function (with the ref property) to bind the dynamic value of a class, the class can change when the ref value changes?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ref

I'm trying to write Vue code like this.

```
<template>
  <h1 :class="{ disabled: aClass() }">Hello</h1>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue";

const a = ref(1);

function aClass() {
  if (a.value === 2) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

setTimeout(()=>{
   a.value = 2;
}, 3000)

setTimeout(()=>{
   a.value = 1;
}, 6000)

</script>

<style>
.disabled {
  background: red;
  color: blueviolet;
}
</style>
```

When I change `a.value` twice, the function seems to be called again, which confuses me.

I would like to know why the background of `<h1 :class="{ disabled: aClass() }">Hello</h1>` changes colors twice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binds in Vue templates are actually computed.

```js
<template>
  <!-- what you write -->
  <h1 :class="{ foo: bar() }">Hello</h1>
  <!-- what it actually does -->
  <h1 :class="computed(() => ( {foo: bar()} ))">Hello</h1>
</template>
```

so they update automatically whenever thier dependencies change

Comment: Thank you, I tried it over the weekend and found that it is indeed the case. Perhaps I should take a look at the implementation logic of computed and the compilation result when binding the function, to understand why these two writing styles yield the same result.

Comment: @Luzz if this answers your question, mark it with green tick.